# When to rewrite UI/javascript or pay up for commercial license?

Tags: javascript, extjs, mobile

I have made a large mistake. At my previous company we had been using Sencha's ExtJs for which we had a license for and i thought it was amazing. While working at that company i had decided to begin writing my own site and mobile app using Sencha's extjs and Sencha Touch for my mobile app(I did not have a license when starting this). At first it was mainly a learning experience and has now grown to completely seriousness where i am on the verge of starting my own business.

Two years down the road and working on my website and app i am coming close to releasing my work into the wild. Currently i would say i would be production ready in about 3-4 month at the pace i am going. The site functionality is finished with a few touch ups here and there and the app is about 60% finished.

Now i decide that yes i do need a license for sencha since i will be using my work to receive revenue. As the last time i had checked for a single developer license it was around 1k which i was fine with. I put all my ducks in a row and prepared to purchase the license.

Now i come to find out that $encha only allows 1-5 developer license packs that goes for $4,835. This is terrible as it increases my startup costs by around 3.5k.

Now i need to make the decision to pony up the $4k+ and have 4 licesnes i do not need and which i may never make my money back on, choose a new framework, or write my own.

I feel i must weight the pros and cons of using an existing framework...

1. Time is takes to learn a new js framework (does it support mobile?)
2. Implementing the framework and replacing all my sencha components
3. Is this new framework have support with updates and correct documentation?

Creating my own..

1. Learning the correct way to implement my own framework
2. Documenting my work
3. My own bug fixes on my framework
4. Create mobile framework

Or pay $4,835 with a new version of Sencha coming out July 1st with a unknown price (surely to be astronomical)

Have i gone too far and need to pay up? Would the rewrite take way too much time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question, though interesting, isn't exactly on topic for this site.  It is more for helping fix issues with existing code more so than "should I do this or that" kind of questions.  I am not sure which stack site this might best fall under.  Best of luck!

Comment: i would use a free framework if i didn't want to code the app myself.

Comment: I don't see how we can possibly help you answer this question.  If you want a financial analysis, you would need to estimate how much calendar time the rewrite would cost you and compare that to the opportunity cost of not releasing your product for that amount of time.  Neither of those are things that we have any data on.

Comment: And, with so many great open source and extensible frameworks that have hundreds of people contributing to them, I have no idea why you'd ever consider building your own framework either.  Find the best match to your style and needs and then build your own scaffolding on top of an existing framework.

Comment: @GaryStorey Thank you Gary although i didnt know quite where to post this. The sencha forums would not give me unbias advice, i dont know which other forums to try(reddit?). The reason i asked here is because its other devs who may have run into this before and could offer help

Comment: @jfriend00 I do need a financial analysis and i will looked for that to check if it would be worth it or not. I currently do not know how to get the cost/time analysis so i will look into that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to evaluate this would be in brass tacks.  Estimate how much it would cost in time/energy or even new staff to refactor your codebase away from Sencha.  If that developer time cost is less than the cost of the Sencha license, I'd seriously consider that.

If it adds up to an equal or greater amount, then go with Sencha.

Edit:  As jfriend00 mentioned, if you're going to be profitable, you should evaluate the opportunity costs as well.  If the money you might make in the time between feasible launch and refactor-launch would offset the developer license such that it cost less than a refactor, that would certainly tip the scales.

Comment: If the product is at all likely to be successful, the real cost of the rewrite is not the developer cost, but the opportunity cost of delaying the product introduction N months.

Comment: Thank you. Ok i will look into the time/cost/energy for the rewrite but how do i mesaure unknown variables as in "Time it takes for the rewrite" and if i profitable or not. I could crash and burn

Comment: @hugeerror - if you can't estimate those things in any way, then you have no financial metric by which to make your decision so you would just have to go with your gut.  And your gut would have to be based on how likely do you think it is that your app takes off fairly quickly and you're perfectly fine to have paid for the Sencha license.  Or, how likely is it that things don't get going very quickly and you regret paying for the Sencha license and not rewriting.  I like to put myself in each possible situation and see how I would feel with each choice.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am going back through all my git history with both my website and my mobile app and trying to get time i spent working on sencha areas. The mobile app currently took around 55days to be where it is now. I am also going back through my git site history and seeing how much time i spent on that as well. I do not know how to set a cost to that time but i am googling to find out. Although I am confident that i would make money but biting this bullet would be rough. And im am not comfortable with making a gut decision. i will keep looking into the data.

Comment: @hugeerror - my personal opinion is that the cost of developing the Sencha code is not relevant - that is a sunk cost (it already happened and is the same in all scenarios going forward).  What is worth doing is estimating the calendar time (months) it would take to do the rewrite and how much that delay in bringing your product to market would cost you in lost revenue opportunity and then compare that lost revenue to the Sencha license cost.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok that makes sense. So i would have to find the potential lost revenue from not going live? Im not sure how to predict what my lost revenue would be since i have no revenue currently.

Comment: @hugeerror - Bound the problem.  Figure out how much revenue would you need to make it worth paying for the Sencha license and then use your gut to guess whether that seems likely or not in the time it would take you to redevelop without Sencha. Imagine each scenario (redeveloping with out Sencha or paying for the license) and then see which your gut feels more comfortable with.  If you're less risk-averse, you will redevelop and save the license money.  If you're confident in likely revenue production from your app, you'll pay the license and get it into the market sooner.

Comment: Awesome! great advice thank you! I will create scenarios for each of these. Based on my competitors right now(which their is only 1) they seem to be increasing their sales exponentially and i believe my product is much more robust. But i do not want them to have anymore time in the market without my product. I will keep researching. thank you again.